# Rigify to ue4-26

Tags: export, rigify

I have a Blender model with a Rigify rig and would like to export it to Unreal Engine 4, except when I export it the model is completely distorted.

I would really like to correct this problem so that the model is correct

Here is the model link (Blender 2.93) mega.nz/file/YtkV1J6J

Original :

[image]

Exported

[image]

Exported but reimported in Blender

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Something is wrong with the download link. It asks for a password.

Comment: The password is : 2Xgqs4uT6QsAVAvcrlXkOmznry3k4Y4aIwIfo4eyeX4